# How to compute the probability of $P(N_A = 1)$ considering an area $A$ in a Poisson point process?

Tags: probability-distributions, poisson-process, point-processes

Knowing that each point process (PP) is characterized by its void probabilities: $f(A)=P(N_A=0)$ as definition: the probability to have 0 points of the PP in the area $A$. And also, knowing that for a homogenous Poisson PP the void probability is $\exp(-\lambda A)$.

I'd like to know if there is an expression for the probability to have only 1 point in the area $A$ and/or a generic number $n$ of points: $P(N_A = 1), P(N_A = n)$ for the case of a Poisson PP?

I'm not looking for the immediate solution, I accept also preliminary inputs of the computation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $\Lambda$ is the intensity measure of the Poisson point process $P$, then the number of elements in a Borel set $B$ is Poisson distributed with parameter $\Lambda(B)$ (if $\Lambda(B) = \infty$, then there are almost surely infinitely many elements in $B$).

This is basically the definition of the [Poisson point process](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_point_process#General_Poisson_point_process).

Comment: Yes, you are right. But I'm looking to the probability to have $n$ elements in a finite area $A$: $P[N_A = n]$. I know that if $A = \inf$ than $P[N_A = n] = 0$ and $P[N_A = \inf] = 1$.

Comment: $N_A$ follows a Poisson distribution with parameter $\Lambda(A)$, i.e. $P(N_a = n) = e^{-\Lambda(A)} \Lambda(A)^k/k!$.

Comment: You mean $n=k$ right?

Comment: Yes, every $k$ in my comment should be an $n$.